# How can I learn all the rules and exceptions about the Vowel Reduction in Russian?

Tags: pronunciation, russian

I've been trying to find the rules and exceptions about [this subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Academia_Espa%C3%B1ola), but I can't really find a good source. At this point, I don't know if I'm supposed to learn this in this way. Sorry, I'm kind of perfectionist person and it bothers me a little not to find what I want.

Comment: https://docviewer.yandex.ru/htmlimage?id=824h-d1ptz8of8aa97guxx2cw606hden3i6ax06qu7dyludx9a8phjhhfcc12wxlri5em7kei1xf9uqob0v0j4qs0l1lafrmezcmwca2&width=900&name=bg-0.png&uid=0

Answer (score 2):

One inexpensive Russian grammar text in which you will find the vowel reduction rules for Russian is the *Schaum's Outline Series* **Russian Grammar**.  If the book is not in bookstores near you, you will find it available (in English) from either Amazon.com, Amazon.uk.com, or Amazon.de.

If you search for the Schaum's Outline grammar on any of the above Amazon websites you will actually be able to look at and study the two pages where the Russian vowel reduction rules are stated and explained.  You can then see for yourself if that is the information you are looking for in your question.

So on the Amazon website(s) if you want to "look inside" the book all you need to do is click on the graphic of the book *if* the "Look Inside" logo is showing.  You can then scroll down to the index page and click on and click on "The Vowels" link [*to page 5*].

I believe the Russian vowel reduction rules you are looking for are those stated and explained on pages 6 and 7 of the book.

Comment: While "looking inside" the book one can click on the "View" tab on the Windows menu bar to increase the text size for better resolution of the text.